# Why is DataView readonly despite "AllowEdit=true"?

Tags: c#, dataview

I have code (below) that I think should allow me to update the underlying tables, but I continue to get a "Underlying data is read only" error.

In the code below, everything I've tried is included.  Clearly, I'm missing something!  A search in SO hasn't found clues...

```
APT.Columns["Selected"].ReadOnly = false;
TWR.Columns["Selected"].ReadOnly = false;
RWY.Columns["Selected"].ReadOnly = false;
APT.Columns["Selected"].Expression = "false";
TWR.Columns["Selected"].Expression = "false";
RWY.Columns["Selected"].Expression = "false";
// DataView with filtered "parent" table data
// Apply user's filter for the "Fix"
DataView dataView = new DataView(APT)
{
    RowFilter = FixFilter(chkboxShowAll.Checked),
    Sort = "FacilityID",
    AllowEdit = true,
};
// RWY and TWR dont have ARTCC (filter item), 
// so we can't filter by that, 
// and "Join" makes the table readonly, 
//so must grab root ID and change manually
DataView dvTWR = new DataView(TWR)
{
    AllowEdit = true                 // Enable editing
};
DataView dvRWY = new DataView(RWY)
{
    AllowEdit = true
};
// TWRs and RWYs have the same ID as the APT, 
// but not may have a TWY or RWY (e.g., Seabase)
// This should update the "Selected" boolean 
foreach (DataRowView dataRowView in dataView)
{
    dataRowView.BeginEdit();
    dataRowView["Selected"] = true;  // *** <- EXCEPTION HERE
    dataRowView.EndEdit();
    int result = dvRWY.Find(dataRowView["ID"]);
    if (result != -1)
    {
        dvRWY[result].BeginEdit();
        dvRWY[result]["Selected"] = true;
        dvRWY[result].EndEdit();
    }
    result = dvTWR.Find(dataRowView["ID"]);
    if (result != -1)
    {
        dvTWR[result].BeginEdit();
        dvTWR[result]["Selected"] = true;
        dvTWR[result].EndEdit();
    }
}
dvTWR.Dispose();        // Commit/close tables
dvRWY.Dispose();
```

At the annotated code line, the exception fires:

> System.Data.ReadOnlyException: 'Column 'Selected' is read only.'

Can anyone tell me the error of my ways?

Comment: BTW, I fixed the "Find" (sort) statements. :)

Comment: I believe (but am uncertain) that `DataView`s are read-only when they cannot map changes back to their source `DataTable`. What is the type of `APT` and what are the other property values of `APT`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I solved this problem by going about it a different way, which turned out better:  I bind the datatable to a datagridview, allow editing, then during loading, I loop the DGV columns to make my one column as not-readonly.  Before I apply the filter, I loop the rows to clear my one column (false), and after the filter I loop again to make those true.  As a plus, I can change individual "Selected" rows.

Answer (score 0):

Dai is correct: A dataview cannot modify static public in-memory tables.  However, a datagridview, bound directly to the datatable, can.

This is a better solution for me, as ultimately I need to display the "selected" rows: I created a datagridview for each table and placed each one in a tab control container. I checked the "Can edit" box for each datagridview in designer.

One can then drilldown to modify each column's readonly property within designer, but I found it easier to assign the readonly property after I read data into datatables from the text files (either one works, and one can change the designer-setting programmatically as they are actually the same property).

Looping the "Selected" column rows true or false is conveniently dependent on the filter applied to the datagridview, making a single calling routine efficient (just do or do not apply a filter to the datagridview(s) and pass the dgv and/or columns to the called routine).

As a plus, users can un/check "Selected" rows. The underlying table is changed! The tables can then be efficiently filtered on "Selected" for other events/output.

```
// schema built in VS designer...
   static public DataTable APT = new SCTData.APTDataTable();
// Table populated from FAA fixed-column text files (cols vary by file)
    ReadFixes.FillAPT();
// Assign the table to the datagridview, apply filter and sort
            DgvArpt.DataSource = APT;
            (DgvArpt.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
            AdjustColumnOrderNSort(DgvArpt);
// Loop the filtered datagrid to make "Selected" col = true
            UpdateSelected(DgvArpt,true);
        private void UpdateSelected (DataGridView dgv, bool hasFilter = false)
        {
            // If the filter is applied, selected boxes are true
            // otherwise, ALL the selected boxes are false
            // But if the ShowAll box is checked, ignore the update
            if (chkboxShowAll.Checked == false)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                {
                    row.Cells["Selected"].Value = hasFilter;
                }
            }
        }
```